# Нужно подобрать к слову "рисовать" несколько антонимов

Tags: антонимы

Как думаете, сколько антонимов можно подобрать к слову "рисовать"? Например: стирать,... А ещё?

Comment: Стереть рисунок. Так точнее, в отношении того, что может быть стёрто, а не выстирано.

Comment: Я откатил, поскольку очень сомневаюсь, что два даже столь уважаемых пользователя могут решить за автора, что он имел в виду вопреки явно написанному. Добро бы еще это модератор был...

Comment: Послушайте, этот вопрос раз за разом скатывается в сомнительные. Но здесь нечего править по сути. Можно дополнить, но это прерогатива автора, я против некорректного вмешательства.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря в каком значении употреблено слово "рисовать".

Рисовать - син. *изображать, чертить, малевать, живописать, описывать; писать (картину); иллюстрировать; обрисовывать, очерчивать, видеть, мыслить; мазать...*

***Стирать, счищать, уничтожать, убирать*** - вот ряд антонимов разной точности в зависимости от значения исходного слова.

Answer (score 0):

"Единственный более или менее близкий антоним - "рисовать" - "писать" (маслом). Художники поймут. Все остальное надумано.

Answer (score 0):

1) Рисовать - уничтожать рисунок (любыми известными способами). Это общий антоним для глаголов со значением "создавать что-то".

2) Уже приведенный вариант: рисовать - писать маслом. По определению, это создавать графическое изображение форм (рисунок) или создавать зрительные образы (живопись). (Вот почему всё же акварель - это рисунок?)

ДЛЯ СПРАВОК

РИСУНОК. Графическое изображение форм, обозначающих некий объем или некое цветовое пятно. Рисунок исполняется на различных основах   с  помощью
различных   материалов   (карандаш, сангина,  акварель).

ЖИВОПИСЬ. Жи́вопись — вид изобразительного искусства, связанный с передачей зрительных образов посредством нанесения красок на жёсткую или гибкую поверхность.

Comment: Вот почему всё же акварель - это рисунок? Потому, что она прозрачна, не укрывиста, тем и хороша (в умелых руках). Бумага сквозь неё должна быть видна, быть эталоном света. Маслом же пишут часто и по тёмному грунту.

Comment: Так в чем принципиальное различие рисунка и живописи? Это противопоставление формы и образа или это только разные техники?  Как очень коротко и по существу дать определение каждому виду?

Comment: Рисунок идёт от линии, живопись - от мазка. Противопоставление, как между вектором и растром: рисунок подразумевает создание условности типа 2D, но понятной умному зрителю, перед живописью (не абстрактной) задачи шире: определить золотую середину между графичностью - условностью 2D и натуралистичностью, гиперреализмом, доступным без напряжения всякому.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score -2):

Рисовать - использовать как инструмент живую линию штриха, контура, силуэта. Испортишь рисунок, если начертишь (линия, как из-под чертёжного инструмента), , смажешь, затрёшь, перейдёшь на мазок или пятно, под которым не видно будет бумаги. Рисовальщики  говорят: замучил, затёр до сапога. Ответ: смазать, замазать, замарать, вымарать, затереть, вытереть, испачкать, запятнать.